# Bash version 3.2 doesn't read in lines/compare lines to a regular expression

Tags: bash, version

I wrote a script in bash at home to solve a problem and "brought it with me" to work (More or less I just found it useful enough to put on my work laptop). It is a bash script and essentially, the only difference between my home version and the work version is where the files are located.

The bash script has this in it:

```
if [ ! -e $finalfile ]; then
    echo >> $finalfile
else
    echo > $finalfile
fi

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ [A-Z]{1,}\( ]]; then
        varName=$(echo "$line" |cut -d "(" -f1 | tr -d "[:punct:]" | tr -d "[:blank:]")
        findComments 
    fi
done < "$getVarNames"
```

When I run this script at home, it reads in every line and prints correctly to final file (which is done in a different function). All the program does is read in each line from a file with the variable names, strip all the extraneous punctuation and blanks, and then checks a different file for comments with that variable name in it in the function findComments. The comments follow a specific form and depending on the form, the program will place some text into the finalfile. So I use read and regular expressions a LOT throughout this script.

The work version of the script does not run. When I use the -x option when I run it, this is what I get:

> + IFS=
>
> + read -r line
>
> =~ [A-Z]{1,}( ]])=c(581,583)
>
> + IFS=
>
> + read -r line
>
> =~ [A-Z]{1,}( ]])=c(584,585)
>
> + IFS=
>
> + read -r line
>
> =~ [A-Z]{1,}( ]]2)=c(586,587)
>
> + IFS=
>
> + read -r line
>
> =~ [A-Z]{1,}( ]]1)=c(588)

I'm not sure why. But it is reading in the line, because the garbage printed after my regular expression in the output are pieces of the lines it's supposed to be reading in. I checked the version of bash and work is running 3.2.25 while I'm running 4.2.25 at home (I think? I know I updated in 2011 or so and I think that's 4.2 or 4.3? But I know I'm at Bash 4.0, also I'm not home atm so I can't check... All I know is for sure I don't have bash v3). I'm also not 100% sure that we're going to update bash anytime soon at work. If things go like they do for most software, then we might not update until a program we run has an incompatibility with bash 3.2. So... like never.

I know bash 3.0 added some regular expression matching and in bash 3.2 there's a change to the regular expression operator =~ so that you don't need to put " " around the regular expression, I read that somewhere but [here's](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#AEN20987) link that I'm looking at right now. What I'm not seeing is any information on read changing in bash v3. There were some changes in v4 but I haven't found any changes that affect how I'm using read.

The long and short of this is that I don't know why this code doesn't work in version 3.2 of bash. I've been looking for an answer wherever I can find information but I legitimately can't figure out what is the problem with my code. I'm pretty sure it's read because I think my regular expression is OK, but is it possibly the regular expression? How can I fix my code so it works on a system with 3.2 on it?

Also on another note, I don't know if there's anywhere that has like... release notes or a changelog or something that I can look at for bash. It would be helpful if I could look at exactly what 3.2 was fixing or like, exactly what was added in my current (home) version of bash.

Comment: Is `IFS''` a typo? It should have been `IFS=''` ?

Comment: Oh, yes! Sorry about that-- I had copied and pasted some of it in but I think this came from a copy where I was messing around with the while.